# Iterate a nested map in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to `scala` and need help in iterating a nested Map in `scala`.

This is what the `Map` looks like.

```
Map(EmpNo -> Map(name -> IntegerType, version -> 1), 
    Name -> Map(name -> StringType, version -> 1), 
    Salary -> Map(name -> DoubleType, version -> 1))
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: i will have to print all the keys and values available the above Map.

Comment: using either for loop or foreach loop.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you are stuck. Even for a scala beginner, this should be straightforward. Do you know how to iterate over a non-nested Map? If so, then it's just doing that for the outer map, then the same thing repeated for each inner map.

Comment: See here. http://alvinalexander.com/scala/create-iterating-scala-string-maps

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

```scala
yourMap foreach {
  case (key, innerMap) => innerMap foreach {
    case (innerKey, value) => // do something
  }
}
```